# multiple async calls issue

Tags: 2010, jsom

Hi Using SharePoint 2010 and making what I think is a chained call. I've inserted another call in the succeed method of the first that also creates another async call. Is this correct? The developer tools shows no error but when I view the final output in the console the second async shows the last entry or sometimes -1.
I'm only creating two items at the moment, which works, but this has the potential of growing to 50 so problems could arise.
The other concern is that when the items are created I like them to be created in the same order always (if possible). Can this be achieved?

Thanks

```
    function SelectTeams(projectItemRef, projectItemID)
{

   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Teams');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="chosen"/><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);  
    // localise vars below
    this.projectItemRef = projectItemRef;
    this.projectItemID = projectItemID;

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededSelectTeams), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedSelectTeams));        

}

function onQuerySucceededSelectTeams(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();        
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        try {
        var oTeamCode = oListItem.get_item('TeamCode');
        var oAssignedTo = oListItem.get_item('AssignedTo').get_lookupId();
        var oID = oListItem.get_item('ID');
        }
        catch(e)
        {
        alert('Incorrect/missing data in Teams list - Check and delete any created Team Requests immediately! - Operation halted');
        throw new Error('Abort javascript - error with Teams list');
        }

        CreateRequests(oTeamCode,oAssignedTo,oID,projectItemID,projectItemRef); // use Id not Value

    }

   alert ('Created IA Requests !');

}

function onQueryFailedSelectTeams(sender, args) {

    alert('SelectTeams Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function CreateRequests(oTitle,oAssignedTo,oTeamID,oProjID,oProjRef) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TeamRequests');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);   
    oListItem.set_item('Title', oTitle);
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededCreateRequests), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedCreateRequests));
}

function onQuerySucceededCreateRequests() {

     console.log('Item created:'+ oListItem.get_id());
    //alert('---  Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());

}

function onQueryFailedCreateRequests(sender, args) {

    alert('Create Requests ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Better try using jquery deferred and promises

Comment: Which aspect will Promises help with? Can arrays be used to help instead of Promises?

Comment: Promises **might** make your code easier to structure. But Callbacks (like you use now) or Promises both have the same effect on processing Async calls. As for your code, you do ``CreateRequests`` in a loop so the server accepts them in those order. Yes a request **might** take some longer to reach the server put not if you have a solid internet connection (on all nodes) If your data 100% MUST be in order you should confirm each addition and then only add the next.

Comment: Having the same order is nice to have, not essential. Whats more important is 1. way of knowing if any item has failed to be created (will this be reported in the failed method). 2. why the result gives -1 or the last entry only in the 2nd success method.